# How can I add a basic authentication in the API header when using ApiController (ASP.NET core / Blazor)

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, blazor

I want to add a basic authentication in the header of my APIs (asking for username and password). My class is using the ApiController property and is inheriting from ControllerBase. I'm just not sure how to move forward from here.

This is what I have so far:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("PDF/[controller]")]
public class ManagerPDF : ControllerBase
{
    //Unrelated code
    public ManagerPDF(Database DB, ManipulatorPDF manipulatorPDF)
    {
        //Unrelated code
        IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings_Authentication.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false).Build();
        string username = config.GetSection("AuthenticationHeader")["username"];
        string password = config.GetSection("AuthenticationHeader")["password"];
        HttpContext.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}")));
    }
//The requests
}
```

This code snippet shown is of the controller of the class and the JSON file is the one storing the username and password. How would I move forward from here? I know it has something to do with adding a request and response to a 401 request to check that the username and password are correct but I'm not sure on how I could add that. Or I could be wrong and it could be something entirely different but that's my understanding of it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For making a basic authentication from beginning ,you can reference https://www.codeguru.com/dotnet/authentication-asp-net/

If you want to make a new request with adding headers here.  Adding header to `httpcontext` won't help. `httpcontext` just represent the request that comes into `ManagerPDF` method which already happen. You need to create a new request here to fetch other api which require authenticate to get data. And you shouldn't use `ManagerPDF` as method name here. The same name of controller class is used for contructor function, such as inject a httpclient.

```
    public class ManagerPDF : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;

        public ManagerPDF(HttpClient client)
        {
            this._client = client;
        }
        public ManagerPDF1(Database DB, ManipulatorPDF manipulatorPDF)
        {
            //Unrelated code
            IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings_Authentication.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false).Build();
            string username = config.GetSection("AuthenticationHeader")["username"];
            string password = config.GetSection("AuthenticationHeader")["password"];

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost:7171/identity");  //other api you want to request
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}")));

            var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);  //then you can use the content you requested.
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }       
    }
```

Comment: I apologize for the late reply. But I just wanted to ask. The function you've just outlined, would I be calling that in every API method that I have in my controller class? Where the request Uri would be the Uri for the API's method?

Comment: @Saucter I modify the answer,you can check the 1st link.

Comment: Thanks! Followed the link and it worked perfectly. I appreciate it mate